# Reset BIOS on Dell by removing battery but now wont boot because time is not set?

Tags: bios, time

I basically get this message:

[image]

If i turn off the computer and turn it back on i just get a black screen with a white cursor blinking. Any ideas?

EDIT

In case anyone else is wondering.  **I DO NOT GET THE F1 OR F2 OPTIONS** it stalls on the time of day. also, if i try F2 or F12 at the beginning of the startup i get a "keyboard failure" message, but as i said, if i reboot i get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Comment: Gordon Bennett!  PRESS F2 and go to setup. It says F1 Key and F2 Key so even if you didn't read what it said you could've tried.. Unbelievable.  And if you did try then SAY SO

Comment: Wow. I said, "pretty much that". I don't get those options. I also said if i turn off the computer i get a blinking cursor. Of course I tried F2, but that returns a "keyboard failure" error. All google searches point to this. But thanks for being a dick

Comment: What specific model of Dell do you have?

Comment: You did not say that originally. That's why my comment and 2 answers told you to Press F2, and you were moved to edit your question. Your edit was a good one. The problem, is the keyboard failure message. It's not recognising the keyboard. The next thing is to try a Ps2 keyboard. or at least try different sockets, different usb sockets, different keyboards. Generally, ps2 keyboard in the ps2 socket, and hey presto. Some older computers didn't recognise USB that well in the early stages, these older computers had USB and ps2 not just usb alone, fortunately.

Comment: You've contradicted yourself too. One time you say "you basically get this message" and you give a screenshot. Another time you say if you turn it off you get a blinking cursor. No deary, if you turn it off you would get a black screen(or perhaps a monitor showing a picture symbolising no signal), but not a blinking cursor.  And you said if you reboot you get a blinking cursor. Are you getting that F1,F2 message, or are you getting a blinking cursor? When do you get each?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a USB keyboard, try borrowing one with a PS/2 connector. I have a PC that won't get me into the BIOS unless I use a PS/2-style keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As Barlop says, Press F2 to enter the BIOS config. Set the correct date and time and save the changes.
Your system clock will then be set and you'll be away.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't get that option

Comment: Have you tried removing the BIOS battery again to see if it resets the options?